# Getting a Parse object crashes with an NSInternalInconsistencyException no data?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am wondering what could cause a crash whenever I try to retrieve a certain PFObject.

I have created a PFObject subclass, STKStake, and saved the object to the server from within my iOS project. However

However, when I try to get the object, I get an error as follows:

> 2014-11-14 15:58:38.947 StakesMockup[429:49445] launching query  for STKStake
>   2014-11-14 15:58:39.143 StakesMockup[429:49445] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "intrinsicID" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18753de48 0x197c7c0e4 0x18753dd88 0x1001be698 0x1001c1720 0x10015e02c 0x10015e3b4 0x18742bfcc 0x1001f1818 0x1001f1a94 0x1001f1d10 0x1001b94d4 0x1001b85a8 0x1001b86c0 0x1001cf9f0 0x1002152bc 0x100214d14 0x1008d4e30 0x1008d4df0 0x1008e19a0 0x1008e2f18 0x19849d2e4 0x19849cfa8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

When I examine the callstack at the time of the crash, it seems that my code calls `[PFQuery findObjects:]`, which calls `[BFTask(Private) waitForResult:]`, which calls `objc_exception_throw`.

I get this crash whether I try to retrieve the object with `PFQuery.findObjects` or by specifying the exact Id. I get it no matter whether I have registered my custom subclass `STKStake`, or whether I have not registered the class at all and am merely trying to return the data as a plain old `PFObject`. And I get this crash despite having verified that the `intrinsicID` key is indeed populated in the data browser.

However, I do *not* get this exception if I create a small sample standalone script on OS X which does nothing but try to get the object as a `PFObject`. That standalone script has code as follows

```
import ParseOSX
Parse.setApplicationId("<appid>", clientKey: "<key>")
let q = PFQuery(className:"STKStake")
println("launching a stake query")
let results  = q.findObjects()
println("results=\(results)")
```

but I *do* get the exception from this nearly identical code in the project:

```
func refreshFromServer(block:(success:Bool, error:NSError!)->Void)
{
  NSLog("ENTRY: refreshFromServer")

  dispatch_async_to_global { () -> Void in
    let query = PFQuery(className: "STKStake")
    NSLog("launching query for STKStake")
    let results1 = query.findObjects()
    NSLog("this line never executes")
    NSLog("results1=%@",results1)
  }
}
```

The line that never executes is never reached because the exception is thrown before then.

FWIW, my custom parse subclass is as as follows:

```
class STKSTake:PFObject, PFSubclassing, NSCopying, Trackable {

   class func parseClassName() -> String? { return "STKSTake" }
   override class func load() -> Void {
       superclass()?.load()
       self.registerSubclass()
   }
   @NSManaged var intrinsicID:NSString
   // etc. etc.
}
```

But I doubt my `STKStake` class is the culprit because, as I mentioned, I get the error even when the class is not registered. Also, I have been able to save objects of the subclass without a problem.

So I'm not sure what about the calling context of within my iOS project causes the query code to crash so spectacularly which works without a problem on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested subclassing on Swift yet (I'm a backend guy more often now). I wonder if NSManaged is causing the initializer to attempt to set a value before the NSObject transitions from the "without data" to the "has data" state, which controls whether a property access throws.

Comment: But if I never register STKStake as a subclass, and am only trying to get the value returned as a PFObject, then there's no NSManaged in the picture, right? OR am I missing something?

Comment: Correct. That's why it would work if you failed to register your subclass.

Comment: what I finally found is that registering STKUser (a PFUser subclass) caused all queries on an unrelated parse class to fail, _whether or not_ that class was represented by PFObject or STKStake a PFObject subclass. So I don't understand how but registering a PFUser subclass was breaking seemingly unrelated things.

Comment: Could you file a bug and I'll have the appropriate person look into it.

Comment: (I'm not sure if this is consistent with what you were saying.) in the end I rewrote STKUser to compose rather than subclass PFUser. I will write up all my findings at end of week after the dust settles.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Hmmm... Subclassing subclasses is definitely a use case we intended (and have unit tests for)

Comment: I believe swift sometimes results in classes reporting their names differently. However I tried re-implementing the STKUser class in ObjC and got the same problem. I also tried registering additional PFObject subclasses, so the problem is not due to just the number of previously registered classes.